# kBottomNavigationBarHeight returning incorrect value

Tags: flutter, bottom-navigation-bar

In my app, I want to overlay another bar above the bottom navigation bar, which stays constant throughout the app. The overlay mechanism works as I desire, except for the fact that the position of it is incorrect when I put it at `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` from bottom.

Code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final bar = SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          childWidget, // the other page that has a BottomNavigationAppBar 
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
            child: bar, //OfflineAd(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This gives me the below where the green-bar overlaps the bottomNavigationAppBar.

[image]

So seems like `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` does not give me the correct value. I tried adding to it the `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom` and `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`, but adding those doesn't get me the right value either. This seems like something that should be really simple. Am I missing something obvious?

If I hardcode, then I can set it correctly for a specific phone model - but obviously that fails on other phones. But for reference, if I hardcode a value of `kBottomNavigationBarHeight + 24`, then for this phone model it sits perfectly on top of the bottom bar:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the question, but `Scaffold`  has `bottomNavigationBar` property add to it https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

Comment: Yeah, aware of that! But my overlay page does not have the bottomNavigationBar, its the child pages that it displays. The overlay page only contains the green bar which is constant across the app. But different child pages have different navigation bars :). So thanks, but can't use that.